# How to manipulate the selected objects on screen in AUTOCAD using VBA?

Tags: vba, autocad

In autocad 2008, I want to learn how to operate the screen selected objects. There is a VBA object named ThisDrawing.SelectionSets, but it is a sets of selections, not the selected objects which are selected by user. Which VBA object represents the user selected objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a "built-in" selection set you can use that represents the currently selected objects.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ss As AcadSelectionSet
    Set ss = ThisDrawing.ActiveSelectionSet
    MsgBox ss.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Many. But I want to really select AutoCAD objects. I found the solution sending [AutoLISP](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-basic-customization/how-do-i-select-the-current-object-in-vba-code-in-autocad/td-p/5290073) code with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to create your own Selection Set and add it to `ThisDrawing.SelectionSets`.

Then when the user clicks on an entity you need to add it to the Selection Set you created.

Finally, you can then step through every entity in the Selection Set to perform some manipulation on it.

I'm sorry I can't offer VBA code as I use C# but this is the process that you need to follow. You can however get help from within AutoCAD itself by hitting F1 and then looking under:

ActiveX and VBA Developer's Guide -> Create and Edit AutoCAD Entities -> Work with Selection Sets

Comment: Thank for your answer. I want to really select objects from VBA but I read that's no possible with VBA. It's not possible modify the [PickfirstSelectionSet](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-D48A1C37-4223-4AAA-B1DC-A746604C49B3) variable. Moreover, I found the solution sending [AutoLISP](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-basic-customization/how-do-i-select-the-current-object-in-vba-code-in-autocad/td-p/5290073) code with VBA.